# How to solve the problem of "Failed to install HAXM" in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

I'm trying to create a virtual emulator in Android Studio, but when I try to install HAXM I get the error "Failed to install HAXM". I already tried to solve it from the BIOS but I don't see any option that tells me to activate "Intel Virtualization Technology".

Is there another way to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: First HAXM is deprecated you don't need it anymore. Second you forgot to add details on your PC like CPU model and used Windows version-

Comment: I want to use Android Studio and it tell me that I need the HAXM. My PC is an i5 4590 and  SO Windows 10

Comment: What Android Studio version do you use? May be you get the HAXM message because the used AS version is outdated? See the different acceleration technologies: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows